# Unable to compile with Rcpp

Tags: g++, rcpp

I use R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again". My system is W10 enterprise 1909.
I assume I have correctly installed Rtools40, since:

1. install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source") terminates correctly
2. I used some code from devtools: has_rtools() and it returns TRUE.

```
    install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source")
    essai de l'URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/jsonlite_1.6.1.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1057910 bytes (1.0 MB)
    downloaded 1.0 MB
    
    * installing *source* package 'jsonlite' ...
    ** package 'jsonlite' correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
    ** using staged installation
    ** libs
    
    *** arch - i386
    C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:244: warning: overriding recipe for target '.m.o'
    C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:237: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.m.o'
    "C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api       -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c base64.c -o base64.o
    [...]
    "C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/"ar rcs yajl/libstatyajl.a yajl/yajl.o yajl/yajl_alloc.o yajl/yajl_buf.o yajl/yajl_encode.o yajl/yajl_gen.o yajl/yajl_lex.o yajl/yajl_parser.o yajl/yajl_tree.o
    C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o jsonlite.dll tmp.def base64.o collapse_array.o collapse_object.o collapse_pretty.o escape_chars.o integer64_to_na.o is_datelist.o is_recordlist.o is_scalarlist.o modp_numtoa.o null_to_na.o num_to_char.o parse.o prettify.o push_parser.o r-base64.o register.o row_collapse.o transpose_list.o validate.o -Lyajl -lstatyajl -LC:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/bin/i386 -lR
    installing to C:/Users/toto26/Documents/R/R-4.0.2/library/00LOCK-jsonlite/00new/jsonlite/libs/i386
    
    *** arch - x64
    C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:244: warning: overriding recipe for target '.m.o'
    C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:237: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.m.o'
    "C:/rtools40//mingw64/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api       -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c base64.c -o base64.o
    [...]
    "C:/rtools40//mingw64/bin/"ar rcs yajl/libstatyajl.a yajl/yajl.o yajl/yajl_alloc.o yajl/yajl_buf.o yajl/yajl_encode.o yajl/yajl_gen.o yajl/yajl_lex.o yajl/yajl_parser.o yajl/yajl_tree.o
    C:/rtools40//mingw64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o jsonlite.dll tmp.def base64.o collapse_array.o collapse_object.o collapse_pretty.o escape_chars.o integer64_to_na.o is_datelist.o is_recordlist.o is_scalarlist.o modp_numtoa.o null_to_na.o num_to_char.o parse.o prettify.o push_parser.o r-base64.o register.o row_collapse.o transpose_list.o validate.o -Lyajl -lstatyajl -LC:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
    installing to C:/Users/toto26/Documents/R/R-4.0.2/library/00LOCK-jsonlite/00new/jsonlite/libs/x64
    ** R
    ** inst
    ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
    ** help
    *** installing help indices
      converting help for package 'jsonlite'
        finding HTML links ... fini
        base64                                  html  
        flatten                                 html  
        fromJSON                                html  
        prettify                                html  
        rbind_pages                             html  
        read_json                               html  
        serializeJSON                           html  
        stream_in                               html  
        unbox                                   html  
        validate                                html  
    ** building package indices
    ** installing vignettes
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
    *** arch - i386
    *** arch - x64
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
    *** arch - i386
    *** arch - x64
    ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
    * DONE (jsonlite)
    
    The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\toto26\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQrssTP\downloaded_packages’
```

One of my issue may come from the location of make:

```
Sys.which("make")
                             make 
"C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\make.exe"
```

instead of the expected

```
Sys.which("make")
## "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"
```

I have asked my IT department to remove the system32 version from my laptop.

Nevertheless, I am not sure it is the root cause of my issues:

```
install.packages("Rcpp", type = 'source')
essai de l'URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_1.0.4.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2751467 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB

* installing *source* package 'Rcpp' ...
** package 'Rcpp' correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:244: warning: overriding recipe for target '.m.o'
C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:237: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.m.o'
"C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/         -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c api.cpp -o api.o
"C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/         -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
"C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/         -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
"C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/         -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c date.cpp -o date.o
"C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/         -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c module.cpp -o module.o
"C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/         -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c rcpp_init.cpp -o rcpp_init.o
"C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o Rcpp.dll tmp.def api.o attributes.o barrier.o date.o module.o rcpp_init.o -LC:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/bin/i386 -lR
/usr/bin/sh: line 8: "C:/rtools40//mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11 : No such file or directory
aucune DLL n'a pas été créé
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcpp'
* removing 'C:/Users/toto26/Documents/R/R-4.0.2/library/Rcpp'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

If I install the compiled version it works, but then I can't use Rcpp:

```
install.packages("Rcpp")
essai de l'URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/Rcpp_1.0.4.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3167452 bytes (3.0 MB)
downloaded 3.0 MB

package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\toto26\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQrssTP\downloaded_packages
```

```
> Rcpp::evalCpp("2+2")
C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:244: warning: overriding recipe for target '.m.o'
C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:237: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.m.o'
"C:/rtools40//mingw64/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/toto26/Documents/R/R-4.0.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/toto26/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQrssTP/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-1.0.4.6"        -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c file477046ea4828.cpp -o file477046ea4828.o
"C:/rtools40//mingw64/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o sourceCpp_2.dll tmp.def file477046ea4828.o -LC:/Users/toto26/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
/usr/bin/sh: line 8: "C:/rtools40//mingw64/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11 : No such file or directory
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
  Error occurred building shared library.
```

Any hints would be more than welcome.
Thanks a lot in advance.
Emmanuel

edit: here is my path:

```
> Sys.getenv('PATH')
[1] "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\toto26\\Documents\\R\\R-4.0.2\\bin\\x64;C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin;C:\\rtools40\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\DockerDesktop\\version-bin;C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\Resources\\bin;C:\\RBuildTools\\bin;C:\\RBuildTools\\mingw_64\\bin;C:\\RBuildTools\\mingw_32\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2018a\\runtime\\win64;C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2018a\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PDFtk\\bin\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin;C:\\RBuildTools\\3.5\\mingw_64\\bin;C:\\RBuildTools\\3.5\\bin;C:\\Python\\Scripts\\;C:\\Python\\;C:\\Users\\toto26\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\toto26\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\bin;C:\\Users\\toto26\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\;C:\\RBuildTools\\3.3\\mingw_64\\bin;C:\\MinGW\\bin;C:\\Users\\toto26\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\toto26\\AppData\\Local\\Pandoc\\;"
```

Comment: Does `Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2")` return and post the correct answer?  That is the test from our documentation, and it does not require any other tools or packages.

Comment: But `aucune DLL n'a pas été créé` doesn't bode well.  You need to check your installation, check the $PATH, etc.

Comment: None of this is a bug in Rcpp as the package build, checks, installs and run fine on a properly setup system.  You are currently fighting Rtools, and Windows.

Comment: Removing a single `make.exe` does not fix your problems. It may even create new problems.  One of the tips / requirement for RTools is that its PATH entry _should come first_ which avoids that problem.

Comment: Dear Dirk, thanks a lot for your comments. I know it is not a bug in Rcpp but a setting of my system. But I can't understand which one. I did add the PATH info. It seems correct to me. And the important folders are coming first.

Comment: Cher Emmanuel, I no longer work on Windows so I can't help you here.  Maybe post to the (very friendly) rcpp-devel list where a few Windows users hang out too.

Comment: Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2") doesn't complete. It can't find g++ which seems to be on the PATH. Strange is that gcc seems to be found when installing a package.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I will post on the rcpp-devel list.

Comment: Sounds good.  Remember to subscribe before you post -- spammers made us do that. Only members get to post.